# Amazon Lex - Manually stopping a conversation

Tags: nlp, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I have created a NLP Chatbot using Amazon Lex. Is there a way to manually stop the voice conversation while it is in-progress?
I tried calling the 
**conversation.reset()** method 
defined in the javascript file (**aws-lex-audio.js**) provided by Amazon, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only restart the conversation, you can change the UserId value and the next request would start a new conversation.